# XML Data not Loading in Chrome, but worked in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have use Microsoft office web component 2003 to load spreadsheet in asp.net web form.

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlSpreadsheet" runat="server" SkinID="XTabChildPanel" 
       CssClass="XTabActivePanel">
                <object id="spreadsheetObject" width="98%" height="400">
                    <param name="src" value="" />
                    <param name="dataType" value="XML" />
                </object>
            </asp:Panel>
```

In UI the data is not loading.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\Script\\FTBankInformationSheet.xml"));
        LoadXmlData(doc, dataList);
        string strReset = doc.InnerXml;
        Response.Write(strReset);
```

I have got the proper xml from code behind. Can someone help me with that and suggest me with codes what i can do.

thanks in advance